# Get Rotation Speed of Disk Sample Code

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, device-driver

Im not really good at VC++ but does anyone have a sample code to get the rotation speed of disk in a computer. I have been working on detecting SSD drives and one solution from researching all day was to get the rotation speed and since SSD have 0 rpm this might be the only way to detect SSD drive.

Comment: I believe this is strongly OS-specific, so you should specify an operating system you're interested in.

Answer (score 7):

From [google wmi ssd detect](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=wmi+ssd+detect&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)

> There is an NV cache manager [interface used for ReadyDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563242(v=VS.85).aspx) which is new to Vista. I think it is testing NV_FEATURE_PARAMETER's NVReadSpeed and NVWrtSpeed values.
>
> Windows 7 detects SSDs by using ATA8-ACS identify word 217: Nominal media rotation rate, with value 0001h as Non-rotating media like solid state devices. But not all SSDs adhere to the ATA8-ACS1 spec section 7.16.7.77, some may need firmware updates.
>
> If you want to lean more about sending ATA commands in Windows, I suggest you to dig aound the  Storage Platform ATA forum. This forum is being archived so act quickly.

---

Also very enlightening:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2009/05/05/support-and-q-a-for-solid-state-drives-and.aspx

**Will disk defragmentation be disabled by default on SSDs?**

> Yes. The automatic scheduling of defragmentation will exclude partitions on devices that declare themselves as SSDs. Additionally, if the system disk has random read performance characteristics above the threshold of 8 MB/sec, then it too will be excluded. The threshold was determined by internal analysis.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but this will work on Windows 10

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\microsoft\windows\storage");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM MSFT_PhysicalDisk");
            scope.Connect();
            searcher.Scope = scope;
            string type = "";
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                switch (Convert.ToInt16(queryObj["MediaType"]))
                {
                    case 1:
                        type = "Unspecified";
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        type = "HDD";
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        type = "SSD";
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        type = "SCM";
                        break;

                    default:
                        type = "Unspecified";
                        break;
                }
            }
            searcher.Dispose();
```

Comment: This is probably a helpful answer to future visitors, but it's not in the same language as the OP is requesting.

Comment: Oh im sorry, didn't notice that. But I'm sure it is possible to use the WMI Command in other programming languages, too

Answer (score 1):

You are likely better off looking for the TRIM command.

```
BOOL IsDriveSSD(){

    DWORD dwBytesReturned;

    HANDLE volhand = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    try{
        volhand = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    }
    catch(...){
        volhand = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    if (volhand == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return FALSE;


    // Test 1: See if we have a TRIM command, if so, we're SSD.
    STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY spq;
    DEVICE_TRIM_DESCRIPTOR dtr;
    memset(&dtr,0,sizeof(DEVICE_TRIM_DESCRIPTOR));
    memset(&spq,0,sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY));
    spq.PropertyId=StorageDeviceTrimProperty;
    spq.QueryType=PropertyStandardQuery;

    BOOL ret = DeviceIoControl(volhand, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
        &spq,sizeof(spq),
        &dtr,sizeof(dtr),
        &dwBytesReturned,FALSE);

    if(ret){
        ret = dtr.TrimEnabled;
    }

    CloseHandle(volhand);

    return ret;
}
```