# C# Hard drive RPM

Tags: c#, hard-drive

Anyone knows how to get the RPM info from a hard drive ?
I am able to access a lot of info through the Win32_DiskDrive WMI class but not that particular one.

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think most HDDs have sensor for that (or at least not one that is makes that info available to the user/motherboard/os)

Comment: Do you wnat the RPM like from the spec or from a sensor?

Comment: As last resort you can build your own "speed test" for hard drive by writing to the disk contents with fixed length (e.g. exactly 10 MB) and measure how long it takes.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard but that would not get the RPM?

Comment: @Oskar I'm just assuming he want to know how fast the HD is.

Comment: See this question: You should be able to p/invoke the api:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814371/get-rotation-speed-of-disk-sample-code

Comment: I just need the RPM spec, not from a sensor.

Answer (score 1):

HDD drive, at least the ones usually used in desktop and Raid Arrays work under a constant RPM so there is no sensor to read. There is however a defined **Rotational Rate** for each device, You can either extract this information from a predefined database based on device [serial number](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/DriveInfoEx.aspx) or guess it using [S.M.A.R.T](http://vasters.com/clemensv/2011/04/11/Reading+ATAPI+SMART+Data+From+Drives+Using+NET+Temperature+Anyone.aspx) data.

in order to guess it you can use the table in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_drive_performance_characteristics) to map rotational latency to device RPM.